# Way to make scoreboards appear with the /gamerule commandBlockOutput false command activated

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

We've probably all heard of the /gamerule commandBlockOutput false command and the /scoreboard command.

I have a set up for a map I'm making in which a repeat command block counts to 100 while a machine character speaks through /say command blocks.  Naturally, in order to count to 100 through a repeat command block, you're going to need to deal with many rapid messages saying that one point was added to the scoreboard.

This of course, drowns out the /say text I WANT people to read.  So, to get rid of the excess messages, I use /gamerule commandBlockOutput false.  Unfortunately for me, that command also makes the scoreboard disappear.

In summary, what I need is a method to make a scoreboard quickly count up 1 by 1 without millions of messages saying so.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi there, as your question stands currently, I am somewhat unsure of what you are trying to ask. This may be due to me not playing Minecraft much, but if you could add a little more detail about what you are trying to do, what you have attempted so far, and what is giving you trouble, it help our experts on Minecraft help you better.

Comment: It looks like you have two accounts. You could ask to get them [merged](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: `/gamerule commandBlockOutput false` shouldn't disable the scoreboard.

Answer (score 1):

`/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar [name of scoreboard]` should work, as long as you replace the "[name of scoreboard]" with the name of your scoreboard